# Help with finding the basis of a polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I know the definitions of a basis and spanning, but I can't figure how to apply the concept to these two problems.

$$Let\:S\:=\:\left\{t^2-t+1,\:t+1,\:t^2+1\right\}\:and\:v\:=\:4t^2-\:2t\:+\:3$$

show that S is a basis of P_2

find [v]_s

Comment: Just put the coefficients in vectors. ${[1,-1,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1]}$ and v vector [4,-2,3] and then proceed as usual.

Comment: @mathreadler I'm going to try that right now.

Comment: @mathreadler for [v]_s I got the column vector $$\left[v\right]_s\begin{pmatrix}1 \\-1 \\3\end{pmatrix}$$

How can go about checking to see if this is right?

Comment: Linear combinations:
$1(t^2-t) + -1(t+1) + 3(t^2+1)$ see if it is equal to v.

Comment: first term should be $1(t^2-t+1) + \cdots $ of course...

Comment: @mathreadler thanks that helped

Comment: @mathreadler Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

From the original question:
$$Let\:S\:=\:\left\{t^2-t+1,\:t+1,\:t^2+1\right\}\:and\:v\:=\:4t^2-\:2t\:+\:3$$

We now store the coefficients into matrices and vectors:

$$M_s = \left(\begin{array}{rrr} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) \hspace{1cm} v = \left(\begin{array}{r}3\\-2\\4\end{array}\right)$$

We can now solve the equation system $M_s x = v$ by dividing the matrix with our vector. First we can conclude that $M_s$ has full rank (i.e. it is a basis for the full space) and therefore the division will succeed. Performing some row operations, we arrive at:

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r} 0&1&0&-1\\-1&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&3 \end{array}\right)$$

We can now write the linear combination $1(t^2 - t + 1) -1(t + 1) + 3(t^2+1)$ which we can confirm simplifies to $v$.